# Is it possible to re-execute javascript in an UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <script> alert("execute again"); </script>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="go" runat="server" Text="Exec JS" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The first time the page renders the script is executed. If I click the button to cause a postback it doesn't execute again.

Is there a way to make it execute the scripts again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo! There's an easy way to get the JavaScript to run again. Put the javascript on the HeadContent portion of your page:

```
<script> 

function BindIt()
{
    alert("execute again"); 
}

</script>
```

then on your page inside the update panel add  portion with a call up to the function that you created for your javascript:

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Sys.Application.add_load(BindIt);
                </script>
...
```

In a project that I was working on, I wanted all of the javascript on the page to run again, so I just put it all into a massive BindIt style function. It took me a while to figure it out and I tried many methods to get this to work but this was the only way I was ever able to get jquery to work with updatepanels

Comment: thank u,it is worked for me in my SharePoint 2010 FBA application

Answer (score 3):

Since ASP is just pushing the raw data, not actually executing it you'll need to probably use the RegisterStartupScript method of the ScriptManager to programmatically inject the script to load after a partial postback.

**EDIT**
More directly, try looking in to [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx) for UpdatePanels. e.g.

Answer (score 3):

If the JavaScript is jQuery related, following link would definitely help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/10/07/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions.aspx

I have personally used the 2nd method mentioned in this article, and it worked for me properly.

Comment: Yep! That's the same article I used. :)